# Unexpected behaviour using delete in inheritence, with base pointer objects pointing to the most derived class

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, virtual

In my code, I have used three classes. See the implementation below:

```
class Medicine 
{ 
   int a;
}

class Pain:public Medicine 
{
   int b;
}

class Comb:public Pain   
{
    string salt,com;
}
```

All classes have just parameterized constructors.
And `call()` is like

```
call()
{
     cout<<"You are in class the_name_of_the_class"<<endl;
}
```

I have defined a function with same name, `call()`, in all of them. (They are not declared as virtual till now)

The code goes like:

```
int main()
{       
    Pain *p[2];
    p[0]= new Comb("Salt","Com",2,110);
    p[1]= new Comb("SALT","COM",1,100);

    p[0]->call();

    delete p[0];
    delete p[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Output: Call goes to Pain’s call()

However, if I make Pain::call() as virtual (Medicine::call() is real), then call goes to Comb’s call(). No issue!

But when I am doing `Medicine *p[2]` instead of `Pain *p[2]`, 
Following error is occuring

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000022ed078 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3b64a760e6]
./a.out[0x400efe]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x3b64a1ecdd]
./a.out[0x400b79]
======= Memory map: ========
```

more things goes here, and this ending with

```
Abort(core dumped)
```

Why so? This again disappear when I use virtual for Medicine::call().(This problem is independent of whether Pain::call() is virtual or not). Why is this happening?

Comment: can you call real `Medicine/Pain/Comb` classes?

Comment: Can you post some minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I am not able to get you. Please elaborate.

Comment: Please provide a minimal implementation of the classes: The base class has a virtual dtor? is `call()` virtual? etc etc

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but smart pointers do inheritance, too.

Comment: But when I am doing Medicine *p[2] instead of Pain *p[2], Following error is occuring - did you mean *p[1]? ;p
Also: could you please include definitions of your classes?

Comment: I have edited the post, please see. Initially, all were real. Then, I made Pain::call() as virtual and no problem. Problem occur when I am using Medicine *p[2] and not declaring Medicine::call() as virtual

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to avoid futile guesses about your class definitions.

Comment: @Smith: sorry, my bad ^^"

Comment: @all I have included definition of classes and function call(). This is a simple program. I am trying to learn using virtual and memory allocation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running into undefined behavior because the base class' destructor isn't `virtual`. Anything can happen.

If you delete a derived object through a pointer to the base class, the destructor must be `virtual`. It's a rule.

Answer (score 0):

According to Scott Mayers"Effective C++" you should define destructor as virtual in base class if you are going to define derived class in the program otherwise the program will behave differently(possibly memory leak, wrong output, crash) during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual destructors are useful when we can delete an instance of a derived class through a pointer to base class:

```
class Base 
{
   // some code
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    ~Derived()
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Here, I didn't declare Base's destructor to be virtual. Now, let's have a look at the following code:

```
Base *b = new Derived();
// use b
delete b; // Here's the problem!
```

Since Base's destructor is not virtual and b is a Base* pointing to a Derived object, delete b has undefined behaviour. In my implementation also, the call to the destructor will be resolved like any non-virtual code, meaning that the destructor of the base class will be called but not the one of the derived class, resulting in resources leak. 
Also, its always safe to declare destructor as virtual when you are using inheritence, whether it seems to be useful or not.